# onclick button border color change

Tags: html, border, buttonclick

Should be fairly simple but I'm lost and all searches result in non-specific answers that don't directly relate to my issue.

Button, border is black but apparently, the "depressed" feel is achieved by changing the border color to black so when I do click the button, it feels "dead". Nothing happens, so it's hard to tell if you miss-clicked or what.

How do you change the "onclick" border color? That way, it can get that "depressed" look again.

```
.addButton {
border-color:black;
border-width:1px;
background-color:#00B0F0;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution is to use css, try the following code:

```
 .addButton:active, 
 .addButton:focus 
 {
     border:0.5em solid #00c; /* here configure as your needs */
     color:#00c;
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm, I feel that's almost there. That does what I want. However, it resets to the "default" look of the button and only shows the style of it when clicked. I assume a small modification of the code above would achieve this but I'm still fairly new to css.

Comment: You need to add also your previous code, i mean you need to have a css rule for .addButton, another one for .addButton:active/:focus as i pointed you and if you like also .addButton:hover this last statement would modify the border when the mouse is over the button. Cheers