# How to change blue outline color of a button when clicked [Bootstrap 4]

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

If I click the following button a blue outline appears:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/Downloads'" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" style="background-color:green;border-color:green">Download</button>
```

How can I change this color?

Comment: can you add it to jsfiddle? so we can test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick button border color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729095/onclick-button-border-color-change)

Answer (score 6):

```
.btn {
  outline-color: red;
}
```

or change it explicitly only when the button is clicked:

```
.btn:active {
  outline-color: red;
}
```

Comment: with the above example its works very well, see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/890g2va1/
But if its not working in your project we need some more context (code) to help you

Comment: is jsfiddle als using bootstrap 4 classes?

Comment: obviously not. Any bootstrap styling will overwrites your css. Now it's your part to find the right selector for this. The basics are posted here.

Answer (score 3):

This completely removes the borders from the buttons. (tested with Bootstrap 4)

```
.btn:focus, .btn:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy this styles to your CSS file and apply the rgba corresponding to the color you need. Hope this will help. :)

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the active pseudo selector.

```
btn:active {
  color:blue;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Answer (score 0):

By default, some browsers add a blue outline for accessibility purposes. This is controlled with the "outline" property:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp

Normally, I remove it and add a border or outline styles for the active state.

```
.btn{
  outline: none;
}

.btn:active, .btn:focus{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the color

```
.btn {
outline-color: red;
}
```

If you need to change the color only when the button is clicked:

```
btn:active {
color:blue;
}
```

[You can read more here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-guide-to-styling-buttons-using-css-f64d4f96337f/)